# recursive batch search for string in all directories

Tags: windows, batch-file

I've never done this before.
I have to do a batch file in which to recursively find a text/string in all directories. 
Does anyone have any suggestions? I have tried some things i found online but nothing seems to work as I want to.

i found this code online, but i have no idea where to put findstr, i've tried after each line but it doesn't work

```
@echo off
rem start at the top of the tree to visit and loop though each directory
for /r %%a in (.) do (
  rem enter the directory
  pushd %%a
  echo In directory:
  cd
  rem leave the directory
  popd
  )
pause
```

Comment: You can use the `FINDSTR` command with the `/S` switch.

Comment: `for /r %%a in (.)`, which should really be ,`for /r . %%a in (*)` anyhow, is not coded to select directories, it is selecting all files. Obviously you cannot `PushD` to a file! Please open a Command Prompt window, type `for /?`, press the 'enter' key, and read the information presented. I would additionally, advise, after you have read that, that instead of just jumping for the easy option, `For /D /R . %%a in (*)`, that you instead use `For /F` with `"Delims="` and `('Dir /B /S /A:D-H')`, which should parse the same directories, but before commencing with the `Do` part of the command.

Comment: As for your question, you haven't made it clear whether you're trying to find a string match in the directory names, or within readable files located within that directory tree. You really need to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61477423/edit) to clarify the task, such that the appropriate advice will be offered.